# Aligning button / boxes side-by-side (instead of vertically)

Tags: html, css

Here is [my reduced text case on CodePen](https://codepen.io/angeles4four-the-lessful/pen/PowyKdX?editors=1100).

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn third">Pull Card At Random</a> 
<a href="#" class="btn third">Choose card from album</a>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.third {
  border-color: crimson;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 40px crimson inset, 0 0 0 0 crimson;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
  width: 240px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #e74c3c;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
}
a:link {
    color: white;
}
```

Notice the two crimson boxes are stacked, one on top of the other. If I wanted to orient them horizontally so they are to the left and to the right of each other, what do I need to change in my CSS?

**Resources I have already used:**

- [Aligning Horizontal Div's Side By Side and Stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984903/aligning-horizontal-divs-side-by-side-and-stacked)
- [How to put two divs side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374918/how-to-put-two-divs-side-by-side/55430864)
- [CSS3 Flexible Box Layout: Everything I Wish I Knew When I Started](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/)
- [Side by side placement instead of vertically placed charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768325/side-by-side-placement-instead-of-vertically-placed-charts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specified if element's should be centered but switching from `display: flex` to `display: inline-block` will give you desired outcome (I guess)

Comment: I recommend using Chrome Dev Tools - by selecting css value of display property you can quickly change it using keyboard arrows - that way you can quickly check all possible options :)